Align text in table when it spans over multiple rows using hspace
I am trying to create a table using the tabular environment where I have different categories in the rows. Then, within each category I have sub-categories with associated values. For better readability between the category and sub-category names I use \hspace to shift the sub-category.
In addition, I use the \RaggedRight, \RaggedLeft I found here, because I want control over the alignment/justification when using p{} within tabular to fix the column size.
The problem is that when the line spans over multiple rows, the second/third rows, etc. are not aligned with the predefined \hspace. It is mainly when \RaggedRight is used. With \RaggedLeft it is OK, and with \centering, I am not sure it is correct.
In the example below, the problem is for line 3 and line 7.
How to fix that? Given that I ideally want to use tabular.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{3.5cm}cc}
%% \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{3.5cm}cc}
%% \begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}cc}
%% \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{3.5cm}cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Group 1}}\\
\hspace{1em}This is line 1 & $4.5000$ & $8.5000$\\
\hspace{1em}This is the 2nd line & $1.2000$ & $6.0000$\\
\hspace{1em}This is the line 3 which is long & $7.9000$ & $2.2000$\\
\hspace{1em}This the fourth line & $2.2000$ & $9.8000$\\
\hspace{1em}This is the line 5 & $1.2000$ & $5.5000$\\
\hline
\addlinespace[0.3em]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Group 2}}\\
\hspace{1em}Line 6 is here & $5.4000$ & $3.9000$\\
\hspace{1em}This is the line 7 which is for sure also quite long & $4.6000$ & $3.4000$\\
\hspace{1em}Finally line 8 & $5.0000$ & $3.4000$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SX!

For a quick fix, you could change
>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{3.5cm}

to
>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{3.5cm}

as this forces hanging indentation from the second line onward. I don't think you need the \hspace{0pt} part for a column that's 3.5 cm wide.
A more elegant solution would consist of changing the table layout from 3 columns to 4, along the following lines.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type
\usepacakge{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} wl{0.25em} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.5cm} cc @{}}

\toprule
 && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Column 2} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Group 1} \\
 & This is line 1 & $4.5000$ & $8.5000$ \\
 & This is the 2nd line & $1.2000$ & $6.0000$ \\
 & This is line 3 which is long & $7.9000$ & $2.2000$ \\
 & This the fourth line & $2.2000$ & $9.8000$ \\
 & This is the line 5 & $1.2000$ & $5.5000$ \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Group 2} \\
 & Line 6 is here & $5.4000$ & $3.9000$ \\
 & This is line 7 which for sure is also quite long & $4.6000$ & $3.4000$ \\
 & Finally line 8 & $5.0000$ & $3.4000$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Off-topic: OP use strange way for number formatting ... (newer seen something like this before).  +1 for nice answer !

You don't want to move right the lines, but to move left the headers.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{\quad} >{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{3.5cm} c c @{}}
\toprule
& Column 1 & Column 2\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Group 1}}\\
This is line 1
  & $4.5000$ & $8.5000$\\
This is the 2nd line
  & $1.2000$ & $6.0000$\\
This is the line 3 which is long &
  $7.9000$ & $2.2000$\\
This the fourth line
  & $2.2000$ & $9.8000$\\
This is the line 5
  & $1.2000$ & $5.5000$\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Group 2}}\\
Line 6 is here
  & $5.4000$ & $3.9000$\\
This is the line 7 which is for sure also quite long
  & $4.6000$ & $3.4000$\\
Finally line 8
  & $5.0000$ & $3.4000$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}


An alternative:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{\quad} >{\RaggedRight\hspace{-1em}}p{3.5cm} c c @{}}
\toprule
& Column 1 & Column 2\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Group 1}}\\
This is line 1
  & $4.5000$ & $8.5000$\\
This is the 2nd line
  & $1.2000$ & $6.0000$\\
This is the line 3 which is long &
  $7.9000$ & $2.2000$\\
This the fourth line
  & $2.2000$ & $9.8000$\\
This is the line 5
  & $1.2000$ & $5.5000$\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Group 2}}\\
Line 6 is here
  & $5.4000$ & $3.9000$\\
This is the line 7 which is for sure also quite long
  & $4.6000$ & $3.4000$\\
Finally line 8
  & $5.0000$ & $3.4000$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}


